# How to configure SVN to block certain file type?

Tags: svn, unix

I have the SVN install in Unix server. I would like to implement a strategy in SVN from accepting certain file type, and then an error message will prompt to alert users. I got some clue that it could be done within pre-commit hook script but I don't know how? May I know how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-commit script is a script that you store in the hooks directory under the root location of an svn repository (the location the server uses, not a location you've checked out to). It can be any sort of script that can be run as an executable - for example a perl, python or bash script, with a correct `#!` line and set as executable.

Every time someone attempts a commit, the commit will be stored as an uncommitted transaction, then the script will be called with two arguments - the path of the repo and the name of the transaction. The script can then use svn utilities such as `svnlook` or `svn log` (usually with the option `-t NAME_OF_TRANSACTION`) to get information about the transaction, and decide whether it's valid.

It produces two important outputs. First of all the exit code will affect whether the transaction goes ahead or not. Anything but 0 will cancel the transaction. So eg in a perl script you would put some test to decide if the filename is valid or not, then do `exit(-1)` if it's not. Secondly if the transaction is rejected, anything written to `stderr` will be displayed to the user to explain to them why their commit didn't go through. So before exiting with a non-zero code, you should print at least something like:

```
print STDERR "Files with extension *.exe cannot be added to version control";
```

Try doing a commit, and then take a look at the different svn tools to get info about that commit, and you should be able to figure out how your script should work. Using command-line arguments `-r 555566` when you know the revision number of a successful commit, should be the same as using `-t NAME` in your script, when NAME is the value passed in as an argument to the script.